# Reduce complexity of the algorithm

Tags: java, arrays

Code :

```
private static String[][] _lists = new String[200][100];

private static int foundIndex (String s) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        if (_lists[i][j].equals(s) == true) {
            return j;
        }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

That's where the problem starts.

If the code I'm looking for is `_list[180][?]`, it's hard to find it.

How can I speed up the my code?

Comment: Are the data sorted in any way? Could you use a different container to `String[][]`?

Comment: Well, you can't. You have an `O(n²)` algorithm there, and with the information given that's the best you can get.

Comment: Hint: this is not python. Do **not** use underscores in names - only exception SOME_CONSTANT = ...

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare to each element in an `nxm` array in time shorter than `O(n*m)`. You can change the data structure to the one supporting fast checks -> if you had a `HashSet` which you can construct in `O(n*m)` time, you'll be able to check if the item is in the set in `O(1)`. This would be efficient if you check twice near the end of the array.

Your code could be simplified by removing `== true` which does nothing. Also I recommend you using Java naming conventions, so your code will be easier to read.

Also, you should probably use [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) class to return both: `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 1):

We can only see part of your code, but in some cases, you could improve speed by using an index in a HashMap:

```
private static Map<String, Point> _index = new HashMap<>();
```

You would need to build that index while you build the matrix:

```
public static void put(int i, int j, String value) {
    _lists[i][j] = value;
    Point pos = _index.get(value);
    if (pos == null || pos.x > i || pos.x == i && pos.y > j) {
        _index.put(value, new Point(i, j));
    }
}
```

Your method foundIndex would then become:

```
private static int foundIndex(String s) {
    Point pos = _index.get(s);
    return pos == null ? -1 : pos.y;
}
```

Comment: You put up the code, I put up some explanations. Nice fit methinks ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I added refactor :)

Comment: @xenteros you did it wrong: _lists has an underscore, and you haven't changed _index into indexMap everywhere.  I did a rollback.

Comment: @MauricePerry I know it has, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @MauricePerry Thank you so much! Its very faster. 100322 pieces of "string" expression were processed at 430 milliseconds. I liked Hashmap :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct: when you have n*m, or *n* elements that you want to search - then you have to iterate all of them.

The only other thing here: sometimes you can *slice* your *n* elements into smaller groups and process these groups *in parallel*.

In other words: you could have say 10 threads, each own working a distinct part of your array. You wait for them to finish; and then you build the minimum over the individual results bigger than -1.

**But**: you are talking about 20000 string comparisons. Yes, that sounds a lot, but isn't much on modern hardware. It only becomes a problem when you call `findIndex()` (hint: method names should follow grammar rules as well!) like 100 times per minute. In that case you rather re-design your data structure. There is no point in using a list when *finding* elements is your primary requirement. You rather use a *set* then!

Or without a re-design: you **sort** the data initially (probably you have to remember the initial i,j then), as you then can apply **binary search** to identify the corresponding element.

Comment: Binary search on 2d array?

Comment: Sure. A 2d array has n*m elements. You can easily define a method that maps a 1d index on a 2d thing.

Comment: Sure, but why would one sort one's 2d data so it behaves as 1d? It's like representing chessboard in `Field[64]` not to mess up with initializing 2d array ;p

Comment: Again: you **only** have to define functions that do f(z)->(x,y) and rev(x,y)->z. I am not saying that you would do that when performance is your primary concern. But it is possible. For sorting, you need to be able to swap a(i) and a(i+1) for example. And as shown, you can use that mapper function to simply compute what a(f(i)) and a(f(i+)) would result to.